# Input With Spaces is Clobbering the Next Input (using cin)

Tags: c++, stream, cin

I ran into an interesting problem when playing around with input streams in C++.

I know that if you attempt to enter a string that contains spaces using `cin` it will truncate the string at the first space unless you use `getline` to get the string.

However I found that even more unexpected results can occur ...  If you have a second `cin` after the first one, and the first `cin` has spaces in it's input, the second input is skipped and its value is clobbered!

**Why does this happen?**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string myString;
    int myInt;

    // I know this will cut off the end of the string
    cout << "Enter a string with spaces: ";
    cin  >> myString;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    cin  >> myInt;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "String: " << myString << endl;
    cout << "Int   : " << myInt    << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter a string with spaces: This is a string

Enter an integer:
String: This
Int   : -858993460
```

***Is there a way to trap on this error so an ignorant user doesn't enter a string with spaces and break an entire program?***

Comment: This is the way stream input works. After you have read "This", the rest of the input is still there in the input buffer. When you try to read `myInt`, it sees "is", recognizes that as not a valid integer and fails to get a value. You can try `getline` or `ignore()` to skip the input you don't want.

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard of `ignore()` before.  I will have to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from `cin` does not read a whole line and then only return part of it. Conceptually, it reads a 'token', usually understood to mean a whitespace-separated string, and then parses it into whatever type you are reading. It has no concept of a 'line'. All the input lines are one consecutive stream of tokens. So after reading a string ("This"), the next token is "is", which of course cannot be parsed as an int, and thus the error.

Comment: Do you know of a way to trap on this error so the program doesn't have unexpected results if a user puts too much junk in the input stream?